# Count instances in an array with PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, count

I'm trying to get a count of how many instances of 'UnitSqFeet' are within a certain range.
For example how many instances are between 0 - 175, or 176 - 300.

Here is a part example of the array (it contains 46 in total).

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [UnitNumber] => 1.03 [UnitSqFeet] => 60.75 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [UnitNumber] => 1.04 [UnitSqFeet] => 160.39 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [UnitNumber] => 1.05 [UnitSqFeet] => 231.55 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [UnitNumber] => 1.06 [UnitSqFeet] => 280.24 )
)
```

The 'UnitSqFeet' is a string so I'm assuming it'll have to be converted somewhere in there.

I managed to get this working as below but it would only output this in the first cell of an html table and not the rest. After doing some research on here I understand it's because I was repeating the query for every cell and after the first it had already retrieved all the rows. Not sure if there's a solution whereby I can just reset the query?

```
$counter = 0;
while ($units = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    $num = $units['UnitSqFeet'];
    $float = (float)$num;
    if ($float > 0 && $float < 175) {
        count($float);
        $counter++;
    };  
};
echo $counter;
```

Comment: where is the data in your array coming from?  If it's in a database, it's a lot easier to do with SQL

Comment: It's in an SQL database attached to our CRM and I don't have access to it but could maybe pass on instruction.

Comment: if you can query the db, you can use case statements to get the groupings and then run a count on those

Comment: Thanks @nomistic.. any chance you could provide a quick example please?

Comment: Why do you count($float) ? That isn't really doing anything.

Comment: Still learning my way. Looking at it now yeah I totally see why it's useless. Thanks for that.

Comment: Not sure what version of SQL you are using, but here's the information from MySQL on how to do selects with a case statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html In other words, something like `case when UnitSqFeet < 175 then 1`

Comment: I change the test array in my answer to a string and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
$count = $count2 = 0;
$result = array();
foreach(array_column($arr,'UnitSqFeet') as $key => $value){
    if(round($value) <= 170){
        if(!isset($result['0-170'])) $result['0-170'] = $count++;
        $result['0-170'] = $count++;
    }else{
        if(!isset($result['171-300'])) $result['171-300'] = $count2++;
        $result['171-300'] = $count2++;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/395597)

Comment: I think you assign an iterator too many times but this will work for an int. I think he said these are strings, do you think this will work cause #justPhpThings ?

Comment: @kripple this'll surely work let me post some fiddle too. Check my update

Comment: You have a bug, 171-300 is returning 4. It thinks 170.34 is 171.

Comment: @n099y that's a functionality not an issue

Comment: Nope don't you know `round`

Comment: Well he didn't ask for rounding, nor is he rounding in his example, but I will finish this now. I was just giving you a chance to fix your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try it here: http://viper-7.com/ofozYB

```
<?php

$UnitSqFeet = array_column($array, 'UnitSqFeet');

$output = array_filter($UnitSqFeet, function ($var) {
    return ( $var >= 70 && $var <= 250 ); // return if between 70 & 250
});

print_r($output);

echo "There is " . count($output) . " values in the selected range";
```

Comment: I think you need to fix the last line.     count(output)

Comment: why is that ? its count($output)

Comment: That tells me nothing, what is the issue ?

Comment: The same thing that you were pointing me within my answer is as within your one too

Comment: umm, no its not .. change the 70 to 161 .. it will NOT see 160.39 as 161. Please stop the spam and stay on topic. Your hitting off the mark here completely, I am sorry I offended you by correcting your answer I was trying to help.

Comment: my comment can be seen posted 4 hours ago. The last edit was 3 hours ago. You fixed it and then responded.

Comment: You must have caught it when it was . ($output) .  for a few moments I suppose, it was never what you suggested thou count(output), you can check the change history if you like, I did to double check, not that it matters.